# Nx run storybook does nothing and terminates

Tags: storybook, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I'm trying to add storybook support to an existing Nx Angular project. More specifically, to a library called `ui`. Following the [docs](https://nx.dev/latest/angular/storybook/overview), I ran:

```
$ npm i -D @nrwl/storybook
$ nx g @nrwl/angular:storybook-configuration project-name
```

The `.storybook` folder was successfully generated under the `ui` library. I added a `*.component.story.ts` file to one of my components folder. But then, when I run `nx run ui:storybook`, it does nothing and just terminates, as shown belown:

[image]

How do I fix this?

### Nx Report Output

```
>  NX  Report complete - copy this into the issue template

  Node : 14.15.4
  OS   : win32 x64
  npm  : 6.14.10

  nx : Not Found
  @nrwl/angular : 11.0.20
  @nrwl/cli : 11.0.20
  @nrwl/cypress : 11.0.20
  @nrwl/devkit : 11.0.20
  @nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx : 11.0.20
  @nrwl/express : Not Found
  @nrwl/jest : 11.0.20
  @nrwl/linter : 11.0.20
  @nrwl/nest : Not Found
  @nrwl/next : Not Found
  @nrwl/node : Not Found
  @nrwl/react : Not Found
  @nrwl/schematics : Not Found
  @nrwl/tao : 11.0.20
  @nrwl/web : Not Found
  @nrwl/workspace : 11.0.20
  typescript : 4.0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you, first, try to fix the name of your `story` file? The files that are recognized as `story` files, are files ending in `.stories.ts`. You can actually look into your `.storybook/main.js` file of your library, and see the pattern of `story` files that are getting read.

However, I believe you should still be getting a warning like "no stories were found". If you change the file name to be correct, and run again, and it still fails to do anything, can you please run `nx report` and post the result here?

Comment: I ran the generator again. This time I passed the flag to auto-generate stories for all components, so they have stories ending with `stories.ts`. Unfortunately, I still get the same behaviour. I've edited the post with the output of Nx report.

Comment: Hi Allan! I cannot really say from the information provided what the problem is. Can you try something for me please?

Comment: 1. Generate a new workspace: `npx create-nx-workspace acme --appName=webapp --preset=angular --style=css` (this will generate a new Nz workspace with an Angular application called `webapp`).

2. Add the `@nrwl/storybook` package: `npm i -D @nrwl/storybook`

3. Generate storybook configuration for the app: `nx g @nrwl/angular:storybook-configuration webapp`

4. Run Storybook: `nx storybook webapp`

Comment: And please tell me if you can run Storybook for your new app in your new workspace! If you can, can you please compare the two configurations, and try to figure out what is different, which may be causing your issue? Thank you very much for this! :)